# Easy to take care and maintain bike

Tags: maintenance

I never had my own bike. I don't know it's pluses or minuses. Now I need to use one so have to get one. Please tell which brand is easy to maintain, not costing arm and leg to have. Easy to change wheels, rubber part etc. Thanx!

Comment: What is your budget? What kind of riding do you plan on doing? The brand of the bike will be less important than the brands/models of the various parts on the bike, which will be decided by your budget and uses.

Comment: A fixie without brakes would be the least maintenance overall (and might be the cheapest) but is hardly practical for a newbie.

Comment: as far as maintenance goes, all bikes will have the same basic process for repairs and maintenance, and as long as you maintain and don't abuse it, even a cheap BSO (bicycle shaped object aka department store bike) can last for quite a long time.

Comment: ^^^ Hahahha, loved your acronym there, Nate Wengert! 

If you're looking for a 'cheap' bike with low maintenance, look at a pre-£150 Hybrid. (Or whatever that is in your currency.) The Viking Ambleside or Viking Kendall bikes would be my shout at this moment in time! Mine's been going for three years, and I store my hybrids outside (I've too many bikes and not enough garages!)

One note; If you DO buy a cheap bike, I highly recommend NOT buying one with TwistGrip/RevoShift shifters, or any similar; They fail crazy easily, so make sure you aim for either thumb shifters or EZFire Shifters :)

Comment: The most failure-prone part of a bike is the setup and adjustment.  Most department store bikes are fairly durable, except that they're never properly set up in the first place, and they don't come with a free adjustment service after a few weeks of use (as would be provided by any decent bike shop).   Pretty much every bike needs to be adjusted after a "break-in" period.   Beyond that, yes, twist shifters are a common trouble point.

Comment: Search for your city's bike rental scheme.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle-sharing_system   Nextbike is in my city, most decent-sized cities have at least one.  That way you have zero maintenance requirements, and some schemes offer free rides under 30 minutes.

Comment: How to know which bike's rubber part of wheels are easily ,not expensively changed?

Comment: thanx.rental in close area.no dutch style cheap. all with at least 6 gears. what best I found is further, my I ask what maintenance issues might have bike with this specification (riding is nearly all the time on enough good roads pavements): > Steel Track Bike Frame 
> Steel Rigid Front Forks 
> Alloy Handlebars 
> Alloy A-Head Handlebar Stem 
> Flip-Flop Rear Hub - Enables the rider to switch between a fixed sprocket or a freewheel 
> Prowheel Solid Alloy Chainset - 46T 
> Front and Rear Alloy Calliper Brakes 
> 700C Deep Section Aero Alloy Wheels 
> 700C x 25C Slick Road Tyres

Answer (score 3):

Items reputed for making a bike easy-maintenance:

- Internally geared hub (ie no derailleurs)
- Enclosed chain case to keep the chain clean
- Puncture resistant tyres (which can still puncture, just less often)
- Somewhere clean and dry to store your bike at room temperature

NOTE the only bikes that are zero-maintenance are rentals/bike loan schemes, and race bikes that come with a team mechanic.  Both cost money.

Items reputed to increase maintenance requirements

- Super light race bikes
- Suspension on bikes, both front and rear
- Derailleur-based gears
- Rotary grip-shifters for changing gear
- Bikes stored outside in the rain and cold

Comment: We're not able to make brand recommendations - that's considered sales/shopping and is off-topic.  Instead I've focused on the features.

Comment: Belt drive? Does not need lubrication.

Comment: Single speed / fixed gear is great. Allows you to ignore maintinance issues much longer due with lower part replacement costs. Less to adjust / fix / repair.

Comment: Thanx! Budget 100 for new. Would add more if i knew maintenance would be easy, getting spare parts not costy or hard. Brand would be helpfull.pitty.as on ebay i saw branded bikes. better to buy good brand second hand well maintaned then one which is not made from good material or hard to maintain? Bikes needed for 1,8 km commute forward and back daily and sightseeing on weekends. Roads no mountains high hills.temped to get bmx from argos but i usualy bmx have low saddle. Bmx look good as are lightweight. Small and like your extended  part, maneuvering. Anyone knowing something similar?

Comment: @Bee - If you're new to biking, with a limited budget, your best bet is to ask around for a friend or neighbor who has a bike they're not using.

Answer (score 2):

If you can find it where you live, a typical Dutch brand bike would have many of the features (as already mentioned by Criggie) that make it very low maintenance:

- Internal hub gears
- Fully enclosed chain case
- Hub dynamo
- Brakes integrated in hub (no need to replace brake pads)

The only disadvantage is that when (rarely) something breaks, you probably have to bring it to a bike shop for repairs. I had this once with the hub gear.

The price might be a bit higher than average, in Europe you'd pay around 700-900 Euro for a new bike. They do typically come with lots of accesories, such as integrated lights, bike rack, integrated lock, ...

Comment: Good points - hub dynamos aren't a thing here, and coaster brakes would be one less thing to deal with .

Comment: As i am truly dumb in bikes, may comments be bit more explaining as now i dont have a clue of what is hub or other parts. Got scared and thinking of getting just bigger scooter as they r so easy. Problem is i need to do distance not standing as travel frequency takes away health to do things after :( any known bike manual to learn parts? What smallest narrowest bike with cheaper but reliable parts is sold? I m turning to bmx as its small but which had high saddle ? Thank you in advance.bike or big wheels scooter is unmakable decision-need a bike but dont want it as afraid i will not handle.

Comment: The bike wheel hubs are basically the axles of the wheels (I'm not a native speaker nor a bicyle expert, so I don't know the exact difference). Typically, bicycles have gears, a dynamo (if it comes with the bike) and brakes that are external and exposed to the weather and other influences. When covered (like a chain case) or integrated in the wheel hubs, they're a lot less exposed and thus need (a lot) less maintenance. For a list of bicycle parts and references see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bicycle_parts.